# Why is my service worker not registering?

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

This is my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
<App />,
document.getElementById('app')
```

);

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            console.log('window loaded')
            navigator.serviceWorker
            .register('./serviceWorker.js')
            .then(reg => {
                console.log('Service worker registered value', reg);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(`Service worker Error: ${err}`);
            })
        })
    };
```

This is my serviceWorker.js file:

```
self.addEventListener('install', (e) => {
    console.log('Service Worker Installed');
});
```

The error I get is:
Service worker Error: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://spark.generaltraffic.co.uk/') with script ('https://spark.generaltraffic.co.uk/serviceWorker.js'): A bad HTTP response code (403) was received when fetching the script.

Comment: Can you check if you have access to the service worker. Just try to open the url in a new tab

Comment: Are you sure that you have `serviceWorker.js` file served by your server? it does not work like webpack, you need build and serve this file separetely. This error means that browser tried to find file `https://spark.generaltraffic.co.uk/serviceWorker.js` but it's just failed.

Comment: How do I build the serviceWorker file in package.json? 
"build": "npm run compile && npm run minify && npm run sw",
    "compile": "browserify -e  ./src/index.js -o ./build/assets/js/client.bundle.js -t [ babelify ] -t [ envlocalify --envfile .env.prod ]",
    "minify": "uglifyjs  ./build/assets/js/client.bundle.js -o ./build/assets/js/client.bundle.js -c -m",
These are some of the scripts from my current package.json which may be relevant.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue. In my case the page requires an Authorization Header to be set, and I'm assuming it doesn't get passed trying to access the serviceWorker.js script which results in a HTTP 403 (Forbidden) response. Did you find a way to fix this?

Comment: Hi arnaud. I haven't managed to fix this.